# ScrollTop with body margin issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the scrolltop function but it stops 67 pixels from the top of the window...

i have a 67 pixel margin set to offset the navbar which sits above a full screen banner image. The navbar is also a little transparent and so the margin is needed, as follows...

```
body {
  margin-top: 67px;
}
```

and the following script...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#MyPage']").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      },900, function(){   
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
</script>
```

the body tag looks like this...

```
<body id="MyPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
```

The scroll works great but stops what I believe to be 67 pixels from the top of the page, seems obvious this is down to my margin to offset the depth of the navbar but how do I overcome this?

I have tried adding +67 to the following line but this doesn't help...

```
scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top+67
```

any ideas would be most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: If the body is scrolling, and the margin is on the body, bearing in mind that the margin is outside of the element, this all makes sense. Can you perhaps try `margin:0; padding-top:67px` instead?

Comment: perfect! thank you so much...sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees.  why did .top+67 not work then?

Answer (score 0):

The following did indeed solve my issue thanks Niet the Dark Absol

```
margin:0; padding-top:67px
```